# Docker compose - can't connect to SQL Server database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to my DB that has been created in my Docker Compose file. It looks like the DB has been successfully created but I am unable to connect to it using SQL Server management studio.

Here is my Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    web:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}umbracoapp
        build: 
          context: .\umbracoapp
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "Testing1234!!"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the database from outside the bridge network that Docker creates, you need to map it's port to a port on the host.

In the container, MSSQL uses port 1433. If that port is available on your host, you can map it to 1433 on the host by adding 'ports' to your db service like this

```
db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    ports:
        - "1433:1433"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "Testing1234!!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Comment: can I access that from the umbraco web?

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: it's the part above in the docker- compose, basically just a website:

web:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}umbracoapp
        build: 
          context: .\umbracoapp
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db

Comment: You are able to reach the database from the umbraco service even without exposing the port, since the umbraco service and the database are on the same Docker bridge network. You just need to use `db` as the name for the database server in your umbraco configuration.